# The navigation links at the bottom don't show up on the other pages, just the first

Tags: php, html, pagination

The navigation buttons to the other pages only appear on the initial page. Is there something I'm missing? The correct number of links appears, but they just disappear. For example, when I click on any other link than the first one, the navigation buttons don't show up on the other pages.

```
      <?php
        if(isset($_GET["page"])){
          $page = $_GET["page"];
        } else {
          $page = 1;
        };

        $start = ($page-1) *10;
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT foodname,calories,kind,carbohydrates,fat,protein,measurement,measurementunits FROM foodItems WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."' LIMIT $start, 10");
      ?>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Food Name
          </td>
          <td>
             Calories
          </td>
          <td>
             Kind
          </td>
          <td>
             Carbs
          </td>
          <td>
            Fats
          </td>
          <td>
             Protein
          </td>
          <td>
            Measurement
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<br><tr><td>".$row['foodname'] ."</td><td>".$row['calories']."</td><td>".$row['kind']."</td><td>".$row['carbohydrates']."</td><td>".$row['fat']."</td><td>".$row['protein']."</td><td>".$row['measurement']."</td><td>".$row['measurementunits']."</td></tr><br>";
          }
        ?>
        </table>
        <?php
          $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(foodid) FROM foodItems WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."' LIMIT $start, 10");
          $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
          $total_records = $row[0];
          $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 10);
        ?>
        <table>
          <tr>
        <?php
          for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++){
            echo "<td><a href='foodDirectory.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></td>";
          }
        ?>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Have you added the footer code on the other pages? Or did you include this page on the other pages? PHP interprets code if you don't tell it what to do it can't guess :)

Comment: sorry if I'm being stupid, but what do you mean?

Comment: What is the name of the page you posted? Is it `foodDirectory.php` ? if it is I think your problem here is that you are limiting the calculation of the total pages. You don't need ` LIMIT $start, 10` on the last query. See if it works just as: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(foodid) FROM foodItems WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");`

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU...sorry if this was an obvious error, but I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: I will add it as an answer so, if it is the right one you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are limiting the calculation of the total pages.

You don't need `LIMIT $start, 10` on the last query. It should be:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(foodid) 
                         FROM foodItems 
                        WHERE userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");
```